# $content not null in shortcode, even though it is self closing

Tags: shortcode

I have a very simple setup like this:

```
add_shortcode( 'code', function( $atts, $content = null ) {
    echo gettype($content);
    exit;
}
```

and contrary to the documentation, even if this tag is self closing like this:

```
[code att="example"/]
```

or

```
[code]
```

it appears that `$content` is an empty string. I am looking for ideas on how to debug this.

Comment: I'm not sure what the issue is, but could you test against: `if( ! empty( $content ) )`? - [PHP Empty()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.empty.php)

Comment: @Howdy_McGee That returns `False`.

Comment: Just to verify I'm reading it correctly, if `$content` is an empty string as you say, `empty( $content )` should return true, `! empty( $content )` should return false but you're saying no matter what it's returning false?

Comment: @Howdy_McGee Sorry, I meant that the condition `( ! empty( $content ) )` is `False`, because it's an empty string. `empty( $content )` does return `True`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I haven't tested this but based on memory, you are misunderstanding how shortcodes work. The "content" isn't passed through the callback the way you seem to expect it to be. The content is extracted from the post body via a [`preg_*` function](https://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/tags/4.2.2/src/wp-includes/shortcodes.php#L200). That, if my memory serves, is going to give you "content" as a string no matter what you try to pass into it.

---

As noted below, the Codex has a line stating that `is_null()` can be used to determine that the shortcode is closed. As far as I can tell, that does not work.

```
function baztag_func( $atts, $content = null) {
  echo gettype($content);
  echo '<br>';
  var_dump($content);
  echo '<br>';
  return "content = $content";
}
add_shortcode( 'baztag', 'baztag_func' );
do_shortcode('[baztag]');

do_shortcode('[baztag]abc[/baztag]');
die;
```

In all cases, the shorcode content comes out as a string. If you look at how shortcodes work, you can see why:

```
$pattern = get_shortcode_regex();
preg_match_all("/$pattern/s",'[baztag]abc[/baztag]',$matches);
var_dump($matches);

preg_match_all("/$pattern/s",'[baztag]',$matches);
var_dump($matches);
die;
```

Make note of the 5th item in the resulting array. ***That item is a `string` in both cases.*** That string is what is going to hit your callback as `$content`.

Now, [Core uses `preg_replace_callback()` with the `do_shortcode_tag()` callback](https://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/tags/4.2.2/src/wp-includes/shortcodes.php#L273). That callback makes it look like `null` might be passed through if content isn't set. To do that it checks the 5th element of that `$matches` array with `isset()`. If `isset()` returns false code should push `null` through, as I read it. But `isset()` on empty content...

```
$content = '';
var_dump(isset($content));
```

Or an array...

```
$content = array();
var_dump(isset($content));
```

Is `true`. Even if this line: `if ( isset( $m[5] ) ) {` in `do_shortcode_tag()` is changed to `if ( empty( $m[5] ) ) {` you still get a string:

```
function do_shortcode_tag_v2( $m ) {
  global $shortcode_tags;

  // allow [[foo]] syntax for escaping a tag
  if ( $m[1] == '[' && $m[6] == ']' ) {
    return substr($m[0], 1, -1);
  }

  $tag = $m[2];
  $attr = shortcode_parse_atts( $m[3] );

  if ( empty( $m[5] ) ) {
    // enclosing tag - extra parameter
    return $m[1] . call_user_func( $shortcode_tags[$tag], $attr, $m[5], $tag ) . $m[6];
  } else {
    // self-closing tag
    return $m[1] . call_user_func( $shortcode_tags[$tag], $attr, null,  $tag ) . $m[6];
  }
}
var_dump(preg_replace_callback( "/$pattern/s", 'do_shortcode_tag_v2', '[baztag]' ));
```

Everything I can think of doing suggests that the information in the Codex is wrong on this one. That is simply not how it works.

Comment: Setting `$content = null` and then using `is_null` is the canonical way of determining whether the shortcode is enclosing or not. [Reference](https://codex.wordpress.org/Shortcode_API#Enclosing_vs_self-closing_shortcodes).

Comment: @Calle : I took some time to go through some things. Please see the edit.

Comment: Thank you for this great answer! Hopefully it will help others as well who fall into the trap set up by the Codex.